# Where Apache base modules are located?

Tags: ubuntu-server

When I type `apache2ctl - l` I get the following list of modules currently compiled into the server:

```
core.c
mod_so.c
mod_watchdog.c
http_core.c
mod_log_config.c
mod_logio.c
mod_version.c
mod_unixd.c
```

but I can't find them anywhere.
I tried `sudo find / -name 'core.c'` - nothing.
I also looked in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`-nothing there as well.

**OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS**

Where can I find those modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find these modules because they're **compiled into the server.** That is, they're *literally* part of the main `httpd` or `apache2` binary instead of being separate module files.

(The packager can choose to compile any modules they want directly into the server. However, some are compiled-in unconditionally; e.g. mod_so can't ever be a separate module file because it is actually the module loader.)

But besides that, only source code files use the `.c` extension; actual compiled modules use `.so` (which is a bit like Windows `.dll`). For example, the mod_rewrite module would be "`mod_rewrite.so`".

Comment: I'm a little bit confused now. Are those modules the same as those in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`? I don't even have `httpd` installed and `httpd.conf` is missing for me. My configuration file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Looks like the official Apache documentation is outdated or something. Why do I need `httpd` then if everything works without it?

Comment: `httpd` is Apache. It's named `httpd` on some distros, renamed to `apache2` on others, but it's still the same Apache. The `mods-available` directory doesn't contain any modules; it contains config files that tell Apache to load modules.